# Dynamic vitual fields? Or pass array from one view to another?

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am having a problem in passing entered data from the edit view to a createPDF view. I first thought about using virtual fields, but I have read somewhere that creating virtual fields on the fly is not good cake practice.
I have a Model Delivery that belongsTo Project. On the edit view of Delivery, I am pulling the related data from Project to pass it to the createPDF view to populate fields on a PDF that gets generated using TCPDF. Users have to type in the product description, quantity of product and asset number on the edit page, these fields do not have to be saved to the database, I just need  to pass them from the form to the function that creates the PDF. Due to the fact that the number of products will vary drastically from Delivery to Delivery (anywhere between 2 - 100), I want the user to dynamically add the product line on the fly to the form, i.e. if product line 1 has been populated, automatically add product line 2. 
After a bit of looking, I found [this](http://topdsoft.com/stories/view/186), which is what I want to do, but not not using database fields, just passing the entered values to another function in an array, like

```
array(
key_1 => array(
qty => '1',
description => 'Blah',
assetNo => '11te';
),
key_2 => array(
qty => '5',
description => 'Blah',
assetNo => 'sdvvs';
)) etc...
```

Anyone got a clue as to how I might go about this?

Comment: you dont' have to save your data in a DB to use the code you linked. In your controller just collect the data and pass it to the view using `$this->set(...)` and then use your array in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the use case:

1. If its the same page, set the data simply to the view
2. If you redirect, store the data in the session, read it from there and set it to the view on your pdf generation page
3. If you want to make it
   persistent, have a single field, serialize the subset of fields, and store the serialized data in that single field.
4. The option you already discoverd.